# Math Research after undergraduate degree and before graduate school

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-process, mathematics, research-undergraduate

I graduated with a bachelor's in math a few years ago and this year I've applied to several graduate programs and have been rejected. One of the graduate coordinators gave me some very helpful feedback and one of the things suggested was to try to get some research published.

I've found many places for undergraduates to publish, but I am technically not an undergraduate anymore, nor am I a graduate student.

Is it feasible for me to get something published given my circumstances?
Are there any places that would accept research at my level from someone who has their undergraduate degree?

Comment: One way would be to publish with a colleague who has the know how, a former teacher. Publish something on magazines, local magazines.

Comment: This seems rather strange advice to me, at least for someone familiar with graduate programs in the U.S. That said, you can find a lot of examples of suitable journals and examples of possible research topics in [Thomas J. Osler's list of papers](http://www.rowan.edu/open/colleges/csm/departments/math/facultystaff/osler/my_papersl.htm), many of which I believe he co-authored with his undergraduate students.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro He had more advice that you would probably consider more typical, but this was the piece of advice that wasn't as straightforward for me. The other big piece of advice he gave me was to take another semester of each Algebra and Analysis. Is that more typical advice? Would you say that my effort would be better spent on other aspects of my application?

Thank you for the link.

Comment: Taking another semester of algebra and analysis is much better for you. For one thing, there is little risk of failure, unlike research which could wind up not going anywhere even if you put in a lot of effort. For another thing, you have the opportunity to do VERY WELL, which would look very good on your application as well as allow one or two teachers to write a very positive recommendation for you.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro You make an excellent point; it would be risky. I think I've been interested in pursuing it since I have some time to kill before the classes start, but I could instead take that time to prepare for those classes.

I've reread the email, and I the advice was to **participate** in research. That may be a little more realistic than publishing. Either way, I think I'll take your advice and put my effort toward preparing for those classes.

Thank you for the advice.